# Sum of values from multiple worksheet Python automation

Tags: python

I have a google spreadsheet with multiple worksheets in it.

I want to add the values from two of those worksheets and update in third worksheet.

Spreadsheet name - Inventory

Sheet1 - Prod1

[image]

Sheet2 - Prod2

[image]

Sheet3 - Final

[image]

final.col1 = Prod1.col1+Prod2.col1

final.col2 = Prod1.col2+Prod2.col2

final.col3 = Prod1.col3+Prod2.col3

For each and every month it has to do till dec 2021. I have to automate this through Python.
Any help please ?

Comment: You can try loading your data into pandas first then from there do what you need to do.

Comment: Please read [ask]. SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet might help you.

```
import pandas as pd
file_location = "Inventory file location"  #Example: "C:Temp//Inventory.xlsx"
df1 = pd.read_excel(file_location, sheet_name=Prod1) # Use your 1st sheetname
df2 = pd.read_excel(file_location, sheet_name=Prod2) # Use your 2nd sheetname
for i in range(len(df1)):
    final_df.loc[i, "Month"] = df1.loc[i, "Month"]
    final_df.loc[i, "col1"] = df1.loc[i, "col1"] + df2.loc[i, "col1"]
    final_df.loc[i, "col2"] = df1.loc[i, "col2"] + df2.loc[i, "col2"]
    final_df.loc[i, "col3"] = df1.loc[i, "col3"] + df2.loc[i, "col3"]
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_location)
final_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Final")
```